# I cannot get the id of the span using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

Hi how can I get the id of my span using jquery. I tried some attempt but it's not working nothing is being log in console.

```
$(function () {

    for (var id = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var dynamicli = '<li class="">' +
            '<img src="path/to/image" class="_xy">' + data[i].name + '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user oncho"></i>' +
            '<span class="myspan" id="' + data[i].id + '></span></li>';
        $('#myullist').append(dynamicli);
    }

    $('#myullist').on('click', '.oncho', function () {
        var id = $(this).find('span').attr('id');
        console.log(id);
    });
});
```

//index.html

```
 <div class="wrapper-n">

    <ul id="myullist"></ul>
</div>
```

**Edit** I change the click event to the class 'oncho' so that when I click icon I can get the span id.

**Edit: I tried using find() but still i cannot get the id it's undefined**

Comment: try `$(document).on('click','#myul .myspan',function(){`

Comment: your code looks fine. Are you sure `data[i].id` has a value?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't think that is needed because `#myul` is already present in the `HTML`

Comment: did you have the script in a dom ready handler

Comment: yes $(function(){// code here});

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed the completion quote of `id`:

```
'<span class="myspan" id="'+data[i].id+'"></span></li>';
//                                      ^
```

**UPDATE**

Use [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) as `span` is not the descendent of `.oncho`:

```
$('#myullist').on('click', '.oncho', function () {

    var id = $(this).next('span').attr('id');
    //               ^^^^^
    console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: @jemz Can you add complete code in question, instead of the algorithm

Comment: @AmmarCSE I updated my post, it will log now but the id is undefined